# Error in Arduino programming

Tags: c++, arduino

I am receiving the following error:

> error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token

Here is the source code that I have written:

```
   void setup() {
     pinMode(1,OUTPUT);
   [...]
     pinMode(13,INPUT);
   }
   int i = 1;
   bool pushed = digitalRead(13);
   bool val = 0;
   randomSeed(analogRead(0));
   void loop() {
     if (pushed == 1) {
       for (i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
         val = random(2);
         digitalWrite(i,val);
       }
     }
   }
```

The variables and the setup are OK; the error is located on the `for` line. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

(edit : added the begining of the script, and sorry for the presentation (first question here)

(edit : looks like the error is not in the "i" definition. I'm using an Arduino UNO SMD Edition, if that helps (and the arduino alpha 0022 linux version of the IDE) )
EDIT: okay guys, solved now. It appears that my version of Arduino IDE was not completely  downloaded, and that I put the `randomSeed` in the wrong place (it should be in the `setup` function.) (when i did put it in the `setup` function before updating, it shown an error message, saying /opt/arduino/lib/math.h was missing something (or something like that, i don't have the full message) ). Thanks for your help and i hope i'll be able to help you in arduino soon!

Comment: Gonna have to see where pushed came from because the for loop is fine

Comment: @RussS: Fine only in and after c99.

Comment: @Als Thanks for the correction! I totally forgot

Comment: in your new edit you have an issue with your `{` and `}`. Check every `{` has a corresponding `}` and every "}" a corresponding `{`. And remember you cannot call function at file scope. To which function  belongs the `randomSeed` call?

Comment: Remember to check the most appropriate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++)
```

is valid in C99/C11 but not valid in C89.

If you use a C89 compiler you have to define `i` outside the for loop clauses:

```
int i;
for (i = 1; i < 9; i++)
```

Also in C89, all declarations have to follow the left brace of a block, you cannot freely mix declarations and statements.

Comment: Just to add here, all declarations in C89 must come at the top of a block. This works here because it's at the beginning of a block (from the context above), but this might not work in general if there are other statements before the loop.

Comment: @FatalError yes, makes sense to add a note in the answer. Done.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have a statement `randomSeed(analogRead(0));` floating in between your `setup()` and `loop()` function definitions.

Move it and any other IO operations to the end of the `setup()` function so you read *after* setting up the pin directions:

```
   int i = 1;
   bool pushed; 
   bool val = 0;

   void setup() {
     pinMode(1,OUTPUT);
   [...]
     pinMode(13,INPUT);

     pushed = digitalRead(13);
     randomSeed(analogRead(0));
   }

   void loop() {
     if (pushed == 1) {
       for (i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
         val = random(2);
         digitalWrite(i,val);
       }
     }
   }
```

That will reading the value of pin 13 into pushed only once ( e.g. you are holding a button when powering it on ); depending what you want it to do you may want to move the read to the start of `loop()` so writes random values whenever the button is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

In C (previous to C99), it's not permissible to define a new variable in the first expression of a `for` loop.  Try declaring your variable `i` at the top of the function instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define pinMode1 1
#define pinMode2 13

bool pushed;
bool val = 0;

void setup() {
  // Declare OUTPUT pin.
  pinMode(pinMode1, OUTPUT);

  // Declare INPUT pin.
  pinMode(pinMode2, INPUT);

  // Set digitalRead().
  pushed = digitalRead(pinMode2);

  // Initializes the pseudo-random number generator.
  randomSeed(analogRead(0));
}

void loop() {
  if (pushed == 1) {
    for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
      val = random(2);
      // Set i to HIGH or LOW.
      digitalWrite(i, val);
    }
  }
}
```